# Why scroll-y doesn't show up?

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to scroll vertically in the `.contacts-wrapper` area, but the scroll bar doesn't show up. I tried different solutions to the problem, but nothing worked out. Can someone please help me?
HTML:

```
<div class="right-side">
        <div class="sponsorship">
            <p class="sponsored">Спонсорирано</p>
            <div class="sponsor">
                <img src="../imgs/coke.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="info">
                    <p class="main">Купи Кока Кола в Маркет Церовище (евтинко)</p>
                    <a href="" class="website">coca-cola.com</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sponsor">
                <img src="../imgs/audi.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="info">
                    <p class="main">Новото Ауди на изгодна цена (чипосано, да са знай)</p>
                    <a href="" class="website">audi.com</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="contacts-wrapper">
                <div class="tools-wrapper">
                    <p>Контакти</p>
                    <div class="tools">
                        <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="contacts">
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="../imgs/guy1.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>Aishe Buzgova</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="../imgs/guy1.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>Aishe Buzgova</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="../imgs/guy1.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>Aishe Buzgova</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="../imgs/guy1.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>Aishe Buzgova</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="../imgs/guy1.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>Aishe Buzgova</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="../imgs/guy1.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>Aishe Buzgova</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="../imgs/guy1.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>Aishe Buzgova</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="../imgs/guy1.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>Aishe Buzgova</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="../imgs/guy1.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>Aishe Buzgova</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="../imgs/guy1.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>Aishe Buzgova</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="../imgs/guy1.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>Aishe Buzgova</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="../imgs/guy1.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>Aishe Buzgova</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="../imgs/guy1.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>Aishe Buzgova</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="../imgs/guy1.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>Aishe Buzgova</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="../imgs/guy1.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>Aishe Buzgova</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.right-side {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 10vh;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #f0f2f5;
}
.sponsor {
  height: 20vh;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sponsor:hover {
  background-color: #d8dadf;
}
.sponsor img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.info {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
}
.main {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.website {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #7c7f82;
}
.sponsored {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin: 1em 0 1em 1em;
  color: #75767b;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.contacts-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
.tools-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.5em 1em;
  border-top: 1px solid #ced0d4;
}
.tools-wrapper p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #65676b;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.tools {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.tools i {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #606770;
}
.contacts {
  width: 100%;
}
.person {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.person img {
  height: 5vh;
  width: 5vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.person p {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

Comment: can you please share a quick drawing or at lease explain what the desired layout is supposed to look like? is it a sidebar you're building? is it responsive? is it supposed to be sticky? etc...very hard to tell by the html you shared, even on codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

Just swap these classes in. I think this is what you want

```
.right-side {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 10vh;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #f0f2f5;
  overflow: hidden; // <-- remove this if you want the full sidebar to be scrollable
}

.contacts-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```